adb reverse not working on adb tcpip/adb network(wirelesss) debugging
I connect my phone to PC for debugging using adb network/tcpip for example adb connect 192.168.xxx.xxx then I enter code in terminal adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000 to connect my flutter app to my laravel localhost api but a message always appears like this adb.exe: error: more than one device/emulator
//this is the input and output command code in my pc terminal

C:\myPc\myflutterapp>adb tcpip 5555
//then I unplugged my USB cable

C:\myPc\myflutterapp>adb connect 192.168.xxx.xxx
`connected to 192.168.xxx.xxx:5555`

C:\myPc\myflutterapp>adb devices
`192.168.xxx.xxx:5555 device`

C:\myPc\myflutterapp>adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000
`adb.exe: error: more than one device/emulator`

C:\myPc\myflutterapp>adb devices
`192.168.xxx.xxx:5555 device`

even though only 1 of my Android phones is connected to the pc, I don't know why the error can occur
I am very confused as to why this could happen.
I have looked for all the solutions and have not succeeded
I hope someone can solve this problem
Very grateful and appreciative for all suggestions and help

please edit your question and include the text output of the command adb devices.

OK, I've edited it

I wasn't asking how many devices you think are connected, but the output of adb devices which can connect multiple devices that were once connected via network. Therefore the exact output of this command is essential.

You can see in the image that I uploaded above that the output coming out of adb device is 192.168.xxx.xxx devices (only one device is connected) @Robert

Seems like you are using adb over IP. Is it the new Android 12 adb network connection or the one from before Android 12. By your description I thought you are referring to device connected via USB as this is the common way to communicate with an Android device. Everything else should be described when posting a question.

I have written the terminal input and output above as an example, when I try on my tablet with android 12 (via network adb) adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000 it runs normally, then when I try on my cellphone with android 8 (via adb network) it displays a message like this adb.exe: error: more than one device/emulator even though I have disconnected the tablet from my PC and I only connected it to my android 8 phone

@Robert ........

I would try adb disconnect + adb kill-server and then start over new. If the problem persists then may be you have a process running that runs a server on your system using port 5554 to 5584 and that is misinterpreted by adb as emulator device.

I have tried it but it doesn't work like adb kill-server && adb start-server | adb disconnect and so on and still haven't succeeded in solving this problem @Robert

@Robert .......

Run adb devices, get the ID of the device you're trying to forward the command to and then run:
adb -s deviceidehere restofyourcommand

is it like this adb -s 192.168.xxx.xxx adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000  ?

I have tried it but it still doesn't work
adb -s 192.168.xxx.xxx reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000
